# Resume a interrupted music player without de-activing the current app's audio session

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

As a new bee, after trying for days, now I can play sound which will interrupted the music player's audio session(this will silent the music player). Then I can also resume the music playing by de-activing my app's audio session.

However, I have another tough task: To resume the music without de-activing my app's audio session.  (I don't want to give up my audio session is because that my app is recording)

two question.

1.Is this workable？
2.If yes, would you please give some hint?

Any answer will be appreciated. Thx